# Spring JPA: Query Annotation Fields select not working for Mongo Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, jpa

I have the following query/projection that works in retrieving data from my data set:

`db.library.find({
  party_id: 'TEST_PARTY_ID', 
  contract_id : 'TEST_CONTRACT_ID'
}, 
{
  library_list: {
    $elemMatch: {
      book_code: 'TST_BOOK_CODE'
    }
  }
})`

In other words: find all documents by party_id and contract_id, and return the library_list elements in the library_list array where the book code matches 'TST_BOOK_CODE'.

I wanted to add this query to my Spring Repository, so I created the following:

```
@Query(value="{party_id: ?0, contract_id : ?1}", fields="{'library_list': {$elemMatch: {'book_code': ?2}}}")
Library findLibraryByPartyAndContractAndBookCode(String partyId, String contractId, String bookCode);
```

This doesn't work. I get back a document where everything is null except for the document Id. If I remove the "fields" attribute, however, I get back the entire document. It looks like the "value" selector is fine but there is a problem with "fields" selector. Does JPA not support the $elemMatch syntax here? According to the javadoc: ["Both attributes allow using a placeholder notation of ?0, ?1 and so on"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Query.html), so I don't think that should be the issue.

Comment: It works for me. Can you add the `LibraryList` & `Library` pojo to the post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to devise a fix for the direct solution but, since this question has not received any replies, I thought I would post my workaround for this.

I had to create a separate repository class and used the following Query to construct the select and projection:

```
Query q = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("party_id")
        .is(partyId)
    .and("contract_id").is(cardId));
q.fields()
    .elemMatch("library_list", Criteria.where("book_code").is(preferenceCode));

List<LibraryList> ret = mongoTemplate.find(q, LibraryList.class);
```